# Is there income inequality by admob ad types

Tags: android, admob, interstitial, adbannerview, admob-rewardedvideoad

I had 3 ad type in my application. rewarded ad with the most impressions but somehow even banners earn more than rewarded ads. Rewarded ads impressions 3 times more than interstitial but same earnings.

[image]

for the first few weeks, there was no such thing, and then suddenly income declined.

[image]

if someone has had a problem before and knows why, can it help me? 
I suspect I'm producing too many rewarded ads, but I couldn't find any documentation

Thanks for any advice or help

Answer (score 1):

Earnings is not just decided with number of impressions, Many factors come into considerations like

- Number of Clicks on that Ad type.
- Location of the user who clicked it for example:A
  click from US will earn more than 10 clicks from India.

Can You check it and still didn't understand please post that information also, it will help me to give better solution for you.

Comment: you are right but it is abnormal to decrease so much at a time isnt it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the reward ads get clicks from countries with really low eCPM or the banner ads get more clicks overall! Anyway this really is weird so I would contact Google Play support and ask them about details.